# Using https instead of http when registering a client package using Yii framework

Tags: php, ssl, https, yii

I'm using https only for login action so when we post invalid password it will refresh the page with a validation error, in this case the https will block all css, js.. resources that  start with http.

BTW I'm using Yii client package registration :

```
  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('login');
```

And login here is an asset package:

```
  'login' => array(
    'js'  => array('js/jquery.js', 'js/bootstrap.js', 'js/other.js'),
    'css' => array('css/other.css'),
    'depends'  => array('jquery'),
    'basePath' => 'theme'
   ),
```

So for example the css file will bock and choose the style of the page to be broken.

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into setting the `basePath` attribute of your package. More details here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#packages-detail